# Saving DataGrid to Bin

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, bin

First off, the .Rows does not work for me.  Believe me, I've tried and I'm just too much of a novice to understand why it won't work.  The below code throws no errors until I click the button. Then it crashes and I get: **System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'History' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'.'**

```
  string file = "history.bin";
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(file, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            bw.Write(historyData.Columns.Count);
            bw.Write(historyData.Items.Count);
            foreach (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow row in historyData.Items)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < historyData.Columns.Count; ++j)
                {
                    object val = row.Cells[j].Value;
                    if (val == null)
                    {
                        bw.Write(false);
                        bw.Write(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bw.Write(true);
                        bw.Write(val.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is `historyData`, and how is `Items` populated? Without that information it's going to be very hard to help you.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow` is WinForms, not WPF. The error message can't be clearer. The elements from the Items collection are obviously no System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow objects.

Comment: historyData is a DataGrid that is populated like so, using get;set;

`private void test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {



            string nowtime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");

            history.Add(new History()
            {
                Timestamp = nowtime,
                Query = deviceToBip,
                IP = ipAddress,
                MAC = macAddress,
                Network = deviceNetwork,
                Mask = networkMask
            });

            historyData.ItemsSource = history;`

Comment: Why are you using winforms datagridviewrow in wpf?

Comment: I don't know why I'm using DataGridViewRow.  I don't know the different between everything, only what I find online while trying to learn.

Comment: Write the property values of the History objects: `foreach (History history in historyData.ItemsSource) { bw.Write(history.Timestamp); ... }`

Comment: Thanks Clemens, this did the trick.  Now to figure out how to read the file back into the DataGrid :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answer - Write the property values of the History objects: foreach (History history in historyData.ItemsSource) { bw.Write(history.Timestamp); ... } – Clemens